# sending an email using python SMTP library credentials security

Tags: python, security, smtp, credentials

When I send credentials using the login method of the python SMTP library, do they go off the wire encrypted or as plaintext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will only be encrypted if you use SMTP with TLS or SSL.